# Server change in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have changed the server and now my VBA code is not working. The paths are still the same, only the code of the server that is different.

```vba
Option Explicit

Sub CreateMail()
    Call PDF

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngSubject As Range
The code of server i    Dim rngBody As Range
    Dim rngAttach As Range
    Dim StrBody As String
    Dim rngRMA As Range
    Dim rngName As Range
    Dim rmaName As Range '[I Miles 26/03/2021]
    Dim strRMAAttach '[I Miles 26/03/2021]
    Dim strFire '[I Miles 08/04/2021]
    Dim strSecurity '[I Miles 08/04/2021]
    Dim strFireLoc '[I Miles 08/04/2021]
    Dim strSecurityLoc '[I Miles 08/04/2021]
    Dim strRMAReturnsLabelLoc '[I Miles 08/04/2021]
    Dim strRMALabel '[I Miles 08/04/2021]
    Dim strRmaFormLoc '[I Miles 08/04/2021]
    Dim strRMAreturnslabelFireLoc '[I Miles 08/04/2021]
    Dim strRMAreturnslabelSecurityLoc '[I Miles 08/04/2021]

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngTo = .Range("O35")
        Set rngSubject = .Range("O36")
        Set rngBody = .Range("O37")
        Set rngAttach = .Range("O38")
        Set rngRMA = .Range("D40")
        Set rngName = .Range("O40")
        Set rmaName = .Range("D40") '[I Miles 26/03/2021]
        Set strFire = .Range("O41") 'Fire RMA First Character [I Miles 08/04/2021]
        Set strSecurity = .Range("O42") 'Security First Character [I Miles 08/04/2021]
        Set strSecurityLoc = .Range("O44") 'Location of Security RMA's [I Miles 08/04/2021]
        Set strFireLoc = .Range("O43") 'Location of Fire RMA's [I Miles 08/04/2021]
        Set strRmaFormLoc = .Range("O34") 'Location of RMA Form.pdf [I Miles 08/04/2021]
        Set strRMAreturnslabelFireLoc = .Range("O33") 'Location of RMAReturnsLabel Location Fire [I Miles 08/04/2021]
        Set strRMAreturnslabelSecurityLoc = .Range("O32") 'Location of RMAReturnsLabel Location Security [I Miles 08/04/2021]
    End With

    StrBody = "Dear " & rngName & "<br><br>" & rngBody.Value & " " & rngRMA

    'Differentiate between Fire and Security file paths depending on the RMA leading number [I Miles 07/04/2021]
    Debug.Print "RMA First char: " & Left(rmaName, 1)
    If Left(rmaName, 1) = CStr(strFire) Then
        'strRMAAttach = "Z:\ComPub\Admin\Sales\RMA Folder\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\Forms & Returns Labels\Fire\RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx" '[I Miles 07/04/2021]
        'strRMAAttach = "D:\Excel\08042021a\RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx" '[I Miles 08/04/2021]
        strRMAAttach = strFireLoc & "RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx" 'Cell refernced Locations [I Miles 08/04/2021]
        strRMALabel = strRMAreturnslabelFireLoc & "RMA Returns Label " & rmaName & ".pdf" 'Cell referenced Locations [I Miles 08/04/2011]
    ElseIf Left(rmaName, 1) = CStr(strSecurity) Then
        'strRMAAttach = "Z:\ComPub\Admin\Sales\RMA Folder\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\Forms & Returns Labels\Security\RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx" '[I Miles 07/04/2021]
        'strRMAAttach = "D:\Excel\08042021\RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx" '[I Miles 08/04/2021]
        strRMAAttach = strSecurityLoc & "RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx" 'Cell referenced Locations[I Miles 08/04/2021]
        strRMALabel = strRMAreturnslabelSecurityLoc & "RMA Returns Label " & rmaName & ".pdf" 'Cell referenced Locations [I Miles 08/04/2011]
    End If
    Debug.Print strRMAAttach '[I Miles 07/04/2021]

    With objMail
        .Display
        .To = rngTo.Value
        .Subject = rngSubject.Value
        .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & StrBody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
        .Attachments.Add rngAttach.Value '.Attachments.Add "X:\ComPub\Admin\Sales\RMA Folder\ALL MK RMA's 2020 MASTER\RMA Form.pdf"'[25032021 I Miles] Replaced filepath from X to Z '.Attachments.Add "Z:\ComPub\Admin\Sales\RMA Folder\ALL MK RMA's 2020 MASTER\RMA Form.pdf" '[25032021 I Miles] Replaced filepath from X to Z '.Attachments.Add "D:\Excel\26032021\RMA Form.pdf"
```

I tried to changed the dynamic paths to actual paths with the code of the server at the start but they only the first half of the code worked. start

An email courier get opened with sender, subject and body but I receive error msg for attachment. Idk how to solve this.

I want a simpler solution that will just take into consideration the new server without having to change much from the actual code.

```vba
If Left(rmaName, 1) = CStr(strFire) Then
     strRMAAttach = "\\\\CFRPAF03.carcgl.com\\ComPub\\Admin\\Sales\\RMA Folder\\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\\Forms & Returns Labels\\Fire\\RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx"     
    strRMALabel = "\\\\CFRPAF03.carcgl.com\\ComPub\\Admin\\Sales\\RMA Folder\\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\\Forms & Returns Labels\\Fire\\RMA Returns Label " & rmaName & ".pdf"
     Debug.Print "Fire RMA Attach: " & strRMAAttach
     Debug.Print "Fire RMA Label: " & strRMALabel 
ElseIf Left(rmaName, 1) = CStr(strSecurity) Then
     strRMAAttach = "\\\\CFRPAF03.carcgl.com\\ComPub\\Admin\\Sales\\RMA Folder\\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\\Forms & Returns Labels\\Security\\RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx"
     strRMALabel = "\\\\CFRPAF03.carcgl.com\\ComPub\\Admin\\Sales\\RMA Folder\\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\\Forms & Returns Labels\\Security\\RMA Returns Label " & rmaName & ".pdf"
     Debug.Print "Security RMA Attach: " & strRMAAttach
     Debug.Print "Security RMA Label: " & strRMALabel
```

Comment: You don't need to escape backslashes in VBA strings.

Answer (score 0):

Consider refactoring the configuration constants into a function so you only need to change in one place.

```
Option Explicit

Sub example()

    Dim rmaName As String, strFire As String, strSecurity As String
    Dim strRMAAttach As String, strRMALabel As String
    strFire = "F"
    strSecurity = "S"
    rmaName = "S-test"
    
    ' original code
    If Left(rmaName, 1) = CStr(strFire) Then
        strRMAAttach = "\\\\CFRPAF03.carcgl.com\\ComPub\\Admin\\Sales\\RMA Folder\\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\\Forms & Returns Labels\\Fire\\RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx"
        strRMALabel = "\\\\CFRPAF03.carcgl.com\\ComPub\\Admin\\Sales\\RMA Folder\\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\\Forms & Returns Labels\\Fire\\RMA Returns Label " & rmaName & ".pdf"
        Debug.Print "Fire RMA Attach: " & strRMAAttach
        Debug.Print "Fire RMA Label: " & strRMALabel
    ElseIf Left(rmaName, 1) = CStr(strSecurity) Then
        strRMAAttach = "\\\\CFRPAF03.carcgl.com\\ComPub\\Admin\\Sales\\RMA Folder\\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\\Forms & Returns Labels\\Security\\RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx"
        strRMALabel = "\\\\CFRPAF03.carcgl.com\\ComPub\\Admin\\Sales\\RMA Folder\\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\\Forms & Returns Labels\\Security\\RMA Returns Label " & rmaName & ".pdf"
        Debug.Print "Security RMA Attach: " & strRMAAttach
        Debug.Print "Security RMA Label: " & strRMALabel
    End If
    
    'revised code
    Select Case Left(rmaName, 1)
        Case CStr(strFire)
            strRMAAttach = GetFullName(rmaName, "Fire", "Attach")
            strRMALabel = GetFullName(rmaName, "Fire", "Label")
        Case CStr(strSecurity)
            strRMAAttach = GetFullName(rmaName, "Security", "Attach")
            strRMALabel = GetFullName(rmaName, "Security", "Label")
    End Select
    
End Sub

Function GetFullName(rmaName, sDept, sType)
    Const SERVER = "\\CFRPAF03.carcgl.com"
    Const FOLDER = "\ComPub\Admin\Sales\RMA Folder\ALL MK RMA's 2022 MASTER\Forms & Returns Labels\"
    Dim sFile As String
    Select Case sType
        Case "Attach"
            sFile = "RMA " & rmaName & ".xlsx"
        Case "Label"
            sFile = "RMA Returns Label " & rmaName & ".pdf"
    End Select
    GetFullName = SERVER & FOLDER & sDept & "\" & sFile
End Function
```